# Automation of Excel file merging

Tags: excel, vbscript, automation

The premise is the following: 
There will be constant generation of separate excel files (db1_01.xslx, db1_02.xslx, db1_03.xslx and so on) from different machines with a variate number of rows with information in them (the column number will not change and will stay the same). The requirement is to put all the rows into one excel master file, with a scheduled automation of merging.

So my first plan of action is to automate placement of all the files into a single folder, this can be done using simple move/ 3rd party folder sync applications and etc. This part is easy.

Now, I wonder what is the best way in practice to automate merging of the rows? I'm thinking reading any file from same location that contains text "db*" and merge them into master, by getting the last unused row in master and copying the additional rows there.

I've seen plenty of Excel/VBS scripts that do merge files, but it will be tough for me to put a script to read the last unused row in the master file and add additional rows from the files, any tips on that? What are the more common commands for this?

And how how do I automate that? Am I able to schedule the .vbs script on a Task Scheduler? Have any of you dealt with this kind of situation? Maybe there is a software that does that you can recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    strPathSrc = "C:\Test" ' Source files folder
strMaskSrc = "*.xlsx" ' Source files filter mask
iSheetSrc = 1 ' Sourse sheet index or name
strPathDst = "C:\Test\Results\Results.xlsx" ' Destination file
iSheetDst = 1 ' Destination sheet index or name

set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkBookDst = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPathDst)
Set objSheetDst = objWorkBookDst.Sheets(iSheetDst)
Set objShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShellApp.NameSpace(strPathSrc)
Set objItems = objFolder.Items()
objItems.Filter 64 + 128, strMaskSrc
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each objItem In objItems
    msgbox objItem.Path
    Set objWorkBookSrc = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objItem.Path)
    Set objSheetSrc = objWorkBookSrc.Sheets(iSheetSrc)
    GetUsedRange(objSheetSrc).Copy
    Set objUsedRangeDst = GetUsedRange(objSheetDst)
    iRowsCount = objUsedRangeDst.Rows.Count
    objWorkBookDst.Activate
    objSheetDst.Cells(iRowsCount + 1, 1).Select
    objSheetDst.Paste
    objWorkBookDst.Application.CutCopyMode = False
    objWorkBookSrc.Close
    objFSO.DeleteFile(objItem.Path)
Next


Function GetUsedRange(objSheet)
    With objSheet
        Set GetUsedRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, .UsedRange.Column + .UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1))
    End With
End Function
```

[VBS to compile information from multiple excel files into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670611/vbs-to-compile-information-from-multiple-excel-files-into-one)

This script reads all the .xlsx files from a location, so no matter how many you have, this will parse each and every one and all all the fields in the Results.xlsx.

You can place this to run at a desired time or frequence with Task Schedules. Just copy the script somewhere and just add the Task Schedule.

Results.xlsx must be created before you run this.

Answer (score 1):

I use that one previously for something like your question.

It copies the filenames in the directory where you have the files you are looking for.

You get the files in one sheet (FILES) and you can choose the one you want to merge.
The merged files will be on (DB) datasheet.

My Workbook was called CopyDb, but you can custom it.

```
   Sub CopyDb()

    Dim xRg, xCell As Range
    Dim xVal As String
    Dim MyPath, MyFileName, Aux As String
    Dim x
    Dim LastRow, LastCol As Long

    Set wsDb = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DB")
    Set wsFiles = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FILES")

    x = Shell("cmd /k type nul > list.txt", vbHide)
    x = Shell("cmd /k dir /A:-D /b > list.txt", vbHide)

    MyPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    MyFileName = "list.txt"
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=MyPath & "/list.txt" _
    , Origin:=xlWindows, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:= _
    Array(0, 2), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    Windows("list.txt").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1)).Copy
    Windows("list.txt").Close

    wsFiles.Activate
    wsFiles.Cells(1, 1).Activate
    wsFiles.Paste
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    wsFiles.Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

    x = Shell("cmd /k del list.txt /q", vbHide)

    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the file names:", , _
                       ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For Each xCell In xRg
        xVal = xCell.Value
        If TypeName(xVal) = "String" And xVal <> "" Then
            Workbooks.Open (MyPath & "\" & xVal)
            Windows(xVal).Activate
            With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
                Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, _
                                 .UsedRange.Column + .UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1)).Copy
            End With
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
            Windows("CopyDb.xlsm").Activate
            LastRow = wsDb.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
            wsDb.Activate
            wsDb.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Select
            wsDb.Paste
            wsDb.Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Hope it helps